# Memory conscious string filtering

Tags: java, string, filter, replace

Lets say I have 500 words:

```
Martin
Hopa
Dunam
Golap
Hugnog
Foo
... + 494 more words
```

I have following text that is about 85KB in total:

> *Marting* went and got him self stuff
>   from *Hopa* store and now he is looking
>   to put it into storage with his best
>   friend *Dunam*. They are planing on
>   using *Golap* lock that they found in
>   Hugnog shop in *Foo* town. `>... text continues into several pages`

I would like to produce following text:

> **-------** went and got him self stuff
>   from **----** store and now he is looking
>   to put it into storage with his best
>   friend **----**. They are planing on
>   using **----** lock that they found in
>   **------** shop in **---** town. `>... text continues into several pages`

Currently I'm using commons method:

```
String[] 500words = //all 500 words
String[] maskFor500words = // generated mask for each word
String filteredText = StringUtils.replaceEach(textToBeFiltered, 500words , maskFor500words);
```

1. Is there a another way to do this that could be more efficient when it comes to memory and CPU usage?
2. What is the best storage for the 500 words? File, List, enum, array ...?
3. How would you get statistics, such as how many and what words were replaced; and for each word how many times it was replaced.

Comment: You can get a memory profiler to see how much memory you are using. You might expect 500 words to use 64 KB of memory.  Unless you are using a phone to run this, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

Comment: If you want your code to be configurable, that is, if the 500 words might change, use a file for them but read them into some other structure.  I would read the words into an array (or an ArrayList as you may not always be able to predict how many there will be).  Arrays will give you the fastest read access and take up the least memory if you're concerned about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't care much apout CPU and memory usage. It should be relatively small for such a problem and such a volume of text.
What I would do is

- have a Map containing all the strings as keys, with the numer of times they have been found in the text (initially 0)
- read the text word by word, by using a StringTokenizer, or the String.split() method
- for each word, find if the map contains it (O(1) operation, very quick)
- if it contains it, add "----" to a StringBuilder, and increment the value stored for the word in the map
- else add the word itself (with a space before unless it's the first word of the text)

A the end of the process, the StringBuilder contains the result, and the map contains the numer of times each word has been used as a replacement.
Make sure to initialize the STringBuilder with the length of the original text, in order to avoid too many reallocations.

Should be simple and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't care about memory much, but in case you do: [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is your friend. It's memory efficient for large sets and it allows very efficient matching. You may want to implement it in a [compressed fashion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Compressing_tries).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need to read the 85KB of text and parse out every word (use split or StringTokenizer). For every word, you need to know if you have it in the set of 500words, and if so, switch it with the corresponding mask.

If you know you have about 500 words, I'd suggest store the 500 words and their masks in a HashMap with initial capacity of about 650 (JDK doc says hashing is most efficient with a load factor of 0.75). Put in the word-mask pairs in the HashMap with a for loop.

The biggest bang for the buck (HashMap) you get is that the get/put operations (searching for the key) are done in constant time, which is better than O(n) in array and even O(log(n)) if you do binary search on sorted array.

Armed with the HashMap, you can build up a SringBuffer while filtering those 85KB of text.
Return the String.toString() from your method and you are done! Regards, - M.S.

PS If you are building the map at a server and doing the filtering somewhere else (at a client) and need to transport the Dictionary, HashMap won't do - it cannot be serialized. Use a Hashtable in that case. If on the same machine, HashMap is more memory efficient. Later, - M.S.